# Checksum done without microcontroller

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, communication, transmitter

How could I transmit data from a device such as a distance sensor or quadrature encoder with an RF transmitter and also transmit a checksum or will I have to use a microcontroller such as the Arduino?

Comment: A arduino is not a microcontroller.

Comment: What's it classified as?

Comment: @JordanBrown, the Arduino is a prototyping platform based on an AVR microcontroller. You could prototype this design on an Arduino and then just use an AVR microcontroller directly along with the minimum support circuitry required.

Comment: The hardware is more of a development board, but all the sugar coating and layers of software around kindof put it into its own classification.

Answer (score 5):

While any logic can be implemented in hardware if you throw enough of it at the problem, a microcontroller is the obvious solution for reading sensors and then sending on the data with some other encoding.  Especially when you talk about generating a checksum, having a programmable part like a microcontroller in the path makes things much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to generating the checksum to be included with the sensor data being sent off to the RF transmitter is to design a finite state machine in hardware. In the "olden days" this may have been done by using a slew of logic chips of various types. These days a very compact solution can be created using a programmable logic device such as a CPLD.

A CPLD may be a more convenient solution than a microcontroller (MCU) if there is other state logic needed to interface to the RF transmitter that is not easily implemented in MCU firmware. This would be especially true for higher speed data rates on the RF link.

On the other hand the MCU approach may be a lot more attractive if the data rates involved are slower and the device can take advantage of the myriad other things that the MCU could also be programmed to support.